# get attribute from xml file

Tags: xml, namespaces, xquery

My XML file entry:

```
<GlobalView xmlns="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships">
    <rels>
        <Relationship Id="rId3" Type="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/officeDocument/2006/relationships/extended-properties" Target="docProps/app.xml"/>
    </rels>
```

---

wanna query attribute Id inside Relationship element.... 
I am using the query given below and it works till element Relationship and not giving me the value of Id attribute.

```
for $file in doc("C:/Users/Raffay/Desktop/RnDxr.xml")
return $file/GlobalView/child::rels/child::Relationship
```

Thanking in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
GlobalView/child::rels/child::Relationship/@Id
```

or in abbreviated form

```
GlobalView/rels/Relationship/@Id
```

Comment: declare default element namespace "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships"; for $file in doc("C:/Users/Raffay/Desktop/RnDxr.xml") return $file/GlobalView/rels/Relationship/@Id this code gives me following error: "XQuery Serialization Error! A document node may not have an attribute node or a namespace node as a child".... :( –

Answer (score 0):

**Use**:

```
declare default element namespace 
     "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";

let $vIds := 
    for $file in doc("C:/Users/Raffay/Desktop/RnDxr.xml") 
     return $file/GlobalView/rels/Relationship/@Id
```

**There are two visible problems with the provided original code**:

1. **The XML document contained in `$file` has a default namespace**. Without a declaration of **[default element namespace](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#id-default-namespace)** all unprefixed names in an expression are considered to belong in "no namespace" and no node would be selected.
2. **The expression aims to select a `Relationship` element**, but the attribute `Id` of this element is what is really is wanted.

Comment: declare default element namespace 
     "http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/package/2006/relationships";

for $file in doc("C:/Users/Raffay/Desktop/RnDxr.xml") 
 return $file/GlobalView/rels/Relationship/@Id

this code gives me following error: "XQuery Serialization Error!
A document node may not have an attribute node or a namespace node as a child"....

:(

Comment: @user399493: Yes, It was supposed that you'll assign these attributes to a variable. I edited my answer and the code now explicitly does so.

Comment: Given following error: 

XQuery Execution Error!
Unexpected end of statement

Comment: without ur ammendment it gives an error that :
[DataDirect][XQuery][err:SENR0001]Top-level attribute nodes are not supported for below given query.

Query:      for $file in doc("C:/Users/Raffay/Desktop/RnDxr.xml")
     return $file/GlobalView/rels/Relationship/@Id

Comment: @user399493: In my solution I am collecting the sequence all attributes in a variable. How to use this variable thereafter is up to you, but you've got an answer to your question.

Comment: No, I want the values of the attributes so I can handle them according to my condition and so far its not giving me the values.... raising an error if try to access "Id" attribute.... TOP LEVEL NODES R NOT SUPPORTED... any help is highly aprciated